# First-order differential equation - integrate between functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to solve this diff. equation:

$y'(t)+\frac{y}{\tau}=\frac{x(t)}{L}$

This is a first-order linear differential equation, so, by solving it, I get:

$y(t)=e^{-t/\tau} \int e^{t/\tau} \frac{x(t)}{L} dt$

Now, the solution my book gives is this:

$y(t)=y(0)e^{-t/\tau}+\int_0^t e^\frac{t'-t}{\tau} \frac{x(t')}{L} dt' $

How can I get this last equation (integrated between two functions)?

**EDIT**:

I calculated the homogenous solution (when $x(t)=0$) and it is: $y(t)=K e^{-t/\tau}, K \in \mathbb{R}$.

So the solutions are:

$y(t)=e^{-t/\tau} \int_0^t e^{s/\tau} \frac{x(s)}{L} ds$  (non homogenous)

$y(t)=K e^{-t/\tau}, K \in \mathbb{R}$ (homogenous)

They can be put in a unique equation, that is:

$y(t)=e^{-t/\tau} \int_0^t e^{s/\tau} \frac{x(s)}{L} ds + K e^{-t/\tau}, K \in \mathbb{R}$

Now, how do I get the solution between two intervals (e.g. $0$ and $t$)?

Comment: You  found a particular solution. You have to add the solution of the homogenous equation.

Comment: Thank you Joelafrite. I added an EDIT to the question. Could you answer, please?

Comment: Can you tell me how do I get, in general, $y (t) $ between two intervals, given $y (t) $? That's what I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

multiply the differential equation by $e^{t/\tau}$ to get an exact derivative on the lhs, like, $$e^{t/\tau}\left(y' + \frac1\tau y\right) = \left( ye^{t/\tau}\right)' = e^{t/\tau}\frac xL \tag 1$$

integrating $(1),$  from $0$ to $t,$  we get $$ye^{t/\tau} - y(0)=\frac1L \int_0^t e^{s/\tau}x(s)\, ds$$
algebraic manipulation of the equality should give you what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you too, abel! But if I do like I did (that is by calculating the homogenous and non-homogenous solutions and get, between $0$ and $s$, $y(t)=e^{-t/\tau} \int_0^s e^{t/\tau} \frac{x(t)}{L} dt + K e^{-t/\tau}, K \in \mathbb{R}$, how can I proceed?

Comment: @sleax, change the dummy variable of integration in your particular solution from $t$ to $s.$

Comment: Why? I choose $t$ as the variable of integration, $0$ and $s$ as extremes.

Comment: excuse-me. I got it. I changed it. Now I got: $y(t)=K e^{-t/\tau} \int_0^t e^{\frac{s-t}{\tau}} \frac{x(s)}{L} ds$. Just a last question: why $K=y(0)$?

Comment: @sleax,  because your particular solution is zero at $t = 0.$ (the range of the integral collapses to the point $0.$).

Comment: I apologize for being insistent and maybe boring, but why should i calculate $K$ when $t=0$?

Comment: @sleax, that is fine. see what happens when you make $t = 0$ in the equation for $y(t) = y_p + y_h$

Comment: $y(0)=K$, but this is only valid when $t=0$, not between $0$ and a generic $t$.

Comment: @sleax, that is true. first order differential equation needs one initial condition. here it happens to be at $t = 0.$

Comment: Ok, I get it. Thank you for everything!

Comment: @sleax, you are welcome.